# fragments use assets with swipe views appcompat

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragments and I can´t use the assets to change my letter. I am using swipe page with appcompat. Here is my code:

```
public class AcercaFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acerca, container, false);
        TextView logouno = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.logouno);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
                .getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
        logouno.setTypeface(typeface);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you resolve `logouno` with that piece of code? or it returns `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this little change:

```
public class AcercaFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acerca, container, false);
        TextView logouno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.logouno);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
                .getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
        logouno.setTypeface(typeface);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The way you applied your font was ok, but you must get your TextView from the View `view`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access views from `getView()` in your `onCreateView` method. In here, you should only return an inflated view:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.acerca, container, false);
}
```

Then, initialize the UI elements like so:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    TextView logouno =(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.logouno);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    logouno.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```